# Translating code from Actionscript 2 to Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, translation

I have this small piece of code I got from a friend, but i can't manage to translate it into working AS3.0. I keep getting compiler errors no matter what i change.
This is the original piece of code and I would really appreciate you tailing a look at a it.

```
laser_nodes = 2;
for (var x=1; x<=laser_nodes; x++) {
    node = _root.attachMovie("laser", "laser_"+x, x, {_x:Math.random()*460+20, _y:Math.random()*310+20});
    node.onPress = function() {
        startDrag(this);
    };
    node.onRelease = function() {
        stopDrag();
    };
}

_root.createEmptyMovieClip("ray", _root.getNextHighestDepth());

ray.onEnterFrame = function() {
    this.clear();
    this.lineStyle(3, 0xff0000);
    this.moveTo(_root.laser_1._x, _root.laser_1._y);
    for (x=2; x<=laser_nodes; x++) {
        this.lineTo(_root["laser_"+x]._x, _root["laser_"+x]._y);
    }
    this.lineTo(_root.laser_1._x, _root.laser_1._y);
};
```

Comment: It would help if you post the specific compiler errors you're getting.

Comment: It would also help if you post the Actionscript 3 code that you've created so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of issues here. Some are syntactical, where others require new methods.

for instance:

- `_root` does not exist in AS3. In AS3 it becomes: `MovieClip(root)`
- `attachMovie` is not available in AS3, you'll have to replace it with a constructor call like `var node = new laser(); ...`
- `onPress` and `onRelease` callbacks are not supported in AS3. you'll need to look into using  the `addEventListener` w/ the `MouseEvent` class. Same with `onEnterFrame` (`Event.ENTER_FRAME`)
- `createEmptyMovieClip()` becomes `new MovieClip();`
- the graphic drawing commands in AS3 are now nested in the `graphics` object of Sprites.

Seems like you'll need to dig into AS3 a little bit for this. It's not a very straight forward bit of code to convert.